# Add a scale-bar to images via command line (with Ubuntu and eg ImageJ)

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagej

at the moment I am using ImageJ (with my Ubuntu 14.04) to manually add Scale-Bars to Images (semi-manually to be precise as I'm using „File → Import → Image Sequence…“).
I have recorded a macro (in ImageJ via: Plugins → Macros → Record...) that looks as follows:

```
run("Blobs (25K)");
run("Set Scale...", "distance=500.5 known=200 pixel=1 unit=µm");
  <<warning: the options string contains one or more non-ascii characters>>
run("Scale Bar...", "width=200 height=8 font=28 color=Black background=None location=[Lower Right] bold overlay");
```

How would the complete command look like when I want to add a scale bar to hundred images (eg /home/$USER/test/*.tif)

Actually I don't necessarily have to use ImageJ. If that was also easily possible with ImageMagick for example that would be totally fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what your images look like or your scale bar. Let's suppose your image looks like this:

[image]

and that you can create a scale-bar on a transparent background using a drawing package like this:

[image]

You can then composite that scale-bar onto your chart like this with ImageMagick:

```
convert -gravity southeast chart.tif scale.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

If you want to move it up 30px and across 40px, do this:

```
convert -gravity southeast chart.tif scale.png -geometry +40+30 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Obviously change the `-gravity` to `southwest` if you want it bottom-left.

If you have a load of images to do - FIRST MAKE A COPY OR BACKUP, then try this

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir annotated
for f in *.tif; do
   convert -gravity southeast "$f" scale.png -geometry +40+30 -composite  annotated/"$f"
done
```

Comment: Ok, that might be something I can work with. I'll try that. Thanks.
Did I get it right that I already need to have a scale-bar.tif in the appropriate size? That means that for each stack of images I have to create an appropriate scale-bar image in advance?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know! I have no idea what your ImageJ code produces, no idea how your scale bar looks, nor how big your images are or if they are all different scales! I am just saying that if you want to superimpose a fixed block of scale-bar or annotation, this may be a way to do it...